# Exclude a category from a query that includes its parent category

Tags: categories, query-posts, conditional-content

I am trying to use ids to control the structure of the output of my categories.  I need to exclude a category that is part of the parent category that is being queried.

What I am trying is :

```
<?php $the_query = new WP_Query('cat=14$cat=-45&showposts=20');
        $permalink = get_permalink( $post_id );
        while ($the_query->have_posts()) : $the_query->the_post();?>    
            <li>
            <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" class="postTitleLink">
            <?php the_title(); ?></a>
            </li>
        <?php wp_reset_query(); ?><?php endwhile; ?>
```

What would be the correct way to show everything in category id 14, except for category 45?  I want to treat 45 differently and show all of its sub categories in a different way.  To try and help describe what I want :

```
#12
- #14
- #14
- #14
 -- #45
  --- #50
   ---- #60
  --- #51
- #14
```

instead of cat=- should I be using conditional statements instead .. !in_category ?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First you should move `wp_reset_query();` outside of the loop instead of resetting the query every post of the loop.

And as for your query you can use `category__not_in`

```
$args = array(
    'cat' =>  14,
    'category__not_in' => array('45'),
    'posts_per_page' => 20
);

$the_query = new WP_Query($args);
while ($the_query->have_posts()) : $the_query->the_post();?>    
            <li>
            <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" class="postTitleLink">
            <?php the_title(); ?></a>
            </li>
<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

this will exclude all posts of category 45.

Comment: Thanks for the code. I'm wondering why something like 'cat' => '14 -45' doesn't work.